# Synchronize Google Calendar?

Tags: ios, swift3, google-calendar-api

Im having a calendar inside my app and it is possible to synchronize that calendar with the apple calendar app on iOS (it then automatically synchronizes with icloud if enabled).

Now I want the same for the google calendar app on iOS but all I could find for now is the google calendar web API. The problem: you need to be online for that but my App should have a full offline support. So I thought maybe it would be possible to access the iOS google calendar app installed on the device to add / remove / modify events.

Is it possible to do so or is there now API for the iOS google calendar app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no API that allows you to interact with the Google Calendar App for iOS.

The samples seen [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios?ver=swift) are specifically for interacting with the Google Calendar service, not with the Google Calendar for iOS app itself.